# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - Sitecore Form Submission

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are upgrading the environment from 9.2 to 10.2 and deploying it in AKS. When we are submitting the form it throws a 500 Internal server error in the console and the form is not able to submit.

> **An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +91
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +300
   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +180

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +516
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +149

[HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +32
   Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.ReCaptcha.<Verify>d__3.MoveNext() +726
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +32
   Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.ReCaptcha.AsyncHelpers.RunSync(Func`1 func) +310
   Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.ReCaptcha.ReCaptchaService.VerifySync(String response) +175
   Feature.FormsExtensions.Fields.ReCaptcha.ReCaptchaValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value) +115
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) +57
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(Object container) +167
   System.Web.Mvc.<Validate>d__2.MoveNext() +352
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +83
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1942
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.ModelBinders.FormDataModelBinder.BindFields(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Guid formId) +955
   Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.ModelBinders.FormDataModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +366
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +446
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +137
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +679
```

Comment: Add error as text instead of screenshot.

Comment: Seems to be a TLS issue. Are you able to confirm using TLS 1.2

Comment: yes, we are using the same TLS 1.2 version.